# Statically Linking glib

Tags: c, glib

I'm trying to statically link glib into my C program.  I'm not sure what's the best way to do this.  I downloaded the code and put it in a subdirectory called glib-2.36.4.  I added "-Iglib-2.36.4" when using gcc.  The glib.h is in the glib-2.36.4/glib directory and in that file there are references to other header files under the glib directory (such as #include ).

I'm not sure why that is since both glib.h and these other header files are at the same level (in glib subdirectory).  I got a compile error due to galloca.h not being found (even though it's there).  So I copied glib.h up one level and those errors went away.  I then got an error about a missing glibconfig.h.  I copied that from my usr directory and that error went away.  I compiled my project and now I'm getting an error about undefined reference to g_ptr_array_new.  I guess this must be because I haven't actually compiled glib.  I had tried to build glib, but when I typed "./configure", but I got this message:

```
checking if arpa/nameser_compat.h is needed... configure: error: could not compile test program either way
```

I did install glib using yum, but I really want this code to run even if glib is not installed on a machine.

Comment: You don't appear to know what you are doing.  The `-l` linker flag is used to specify the compiled library (`.a` file in your case) and you don't appear to have successfully compiled the library, which is a pre-requisite to linking against it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install both glib and **glib-dev** via yum, compile using ./configure, *(take a look in the ./configure script to see if there are any flags you need to supply or defines you need to produce the static build)*, **without** moving any files about, and then you need to compile your code using -i path/to/glib/includes and link with -L path/to/built/static/library

Comment: I have those packages installed, but I still get the error I mentioned above when I execute "./configure".  I downloaded the code again and am still facing the same issue.  I was able to compile and run my code using the -I and -L arguments, but my understanding is that requires a user to already have glib installed.  Is that right?

Comment: __Not__ if you are statically linking with the .a library rather than the .so library.